# How to get the previous position of a number in an array before it was sorted?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a code that sorts my array of numbers from descending order but I also want to know the nth position of the numbers in the array before it was sorted after the sort. How do i get that?

```
    int main ()
   {
    int H[200];
    int i,j;
    double a;

       for( i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
       {
          for( j = i+1; j < 200; ++j)
       {
           if(H[i] < H[j])
             {
               a = H[i];
               H[i] = H[j];
               H[j] = a;
             }
        }
      }
    printf("H in descending order \n");

     for ( i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
       {
          printf("%lf \n",H[i];
       }


    }
```

Comment: Make a copy of the array before you sort.

Comment: Make a copy of the array before sorting it. Btw the `main` function should not be `void`, it should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: What purpose do the `.mod` in the code snippet have?

Comment: Personally, I'd use an array of structures, where each structure contains both the data, as well as the original index of the data.

Comment: I had some typo which has now been cleared. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you are serious about this website and about getting better at coding, I would start by choosing a better user name.

Comment: Maybe you need a better understanding of humour Stephen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility to get this result is, like mentioned above by Nominal Animal, to store the values in a structure, and sort the structure.

When you are sorting, you have to be careful about data-types. You are mixing int and double. Also the `%lf` is not meant to print `int` values.

The following code orders a list of `long` and also provide the initial index of the number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sort_s{
  long number;
  long index;
}sort_t;

int main(void){

  sort_t S[200];
  long H[200];
  long i,j;
  long a;

  for(i=0;i<200;i++){
    S[i].number = H[i];
    S[i].number = i; /*for testing*/
    S[i].index  = i;
  }

  for( i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
  {
    for( j = i+1; j < 200; ++j)
      {
        if(S[i].number < S[j].number)
          {
            a = S[i].number;
            S[i].number = S[j].number;
            S[j].number = a;
          }
      }
  }
  printf("H in descending order \n");

  for ( i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
  {
    printf("%ld at pos: %ld \n",S[i].number,S[i].index);
  }


  return 0;

}
```

Comment: shouldn't you also swap the `S[x].index` as well, so that the value+index are preserved?

Comment: I made a structure and performed the sorting function. This worked perfectly so thank you for the idea.